# How to call method from a reference send to annotation in java

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

I have a Interface **I** and a Abstract Class **A** , I have My custom annotation **MyAnnotation**  which should take parameter as subclass **S** of **A**, now while processing annotation I want to call method of concrete class **S**

```
public interface I{
   void m1();
}

public abstract class A implements I {
    public abstract void m1();
}

public @interface MyAnnotation {
    public Class< ? extends A> ref();
    public Class< ? super A> ref2();
}

public S extends A{
    public void m1() {}
}
```

I am annotating method like

```
@MyAnnotation(ref= new XX() )  or @MyAnnotation(ref= XX.class )
@MyAnnotation(ref= new yy() ) or @MyAnnotation(ref= yy.class )
```

whichever works

```
//In spring aspect before processing I am getting method annotation and trying to call m1()  
annotation.ref().m1() //Error
annotation.ref2().m1() //Error
```

Comment: `abstarct` and `public S extends A` aren't correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `new XX()` in an annotation. Annotations parameters can use a very specific set of types:

> - primitive
> - String
> - Class
> - an Enum
> - another Annotation
> - an array of any of the above

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458556/1898563).

So to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish, you'd have to use a class.

You would then have to use reflection to create an instance and invoke the method.

```
Class<?> clazz = annotation.ref();
I instance = (I) cls.getConstructor().newInstance();
instance.m1();
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511559/generate-java-class-and-call-its-method-dynamically).

Your classes must all have no-argument constructors, else you'll only be able to instantiate some this way but not others (leading you to have to conditionally branch based on the class).

Comment: I think `((I) cls.newInstance()).m1()` is a better option than `...getMethod(...).invoke(...)`

Comment: @ernest_k `newInstance` is deprecated since 9; it's better to call `Constructor::newInstance`

Comment: @Eugene That's right. My comment is just about avoiding the `getMethod(...).invoke(...)` part, if you notice...

Comment: @ernest_k + Eugene, You're both right. It was a bit of a lazy answer, mostly just copied and pasted from the sources I listed. I've improved it now

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that simply like that. You need an instance of the class first.
If your `A` class is a `Spring's` bean, you can inject `ApplicationContext` and get the bean from there. Then you can call a method.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

void test(MyAnnotation annotation) {
    A bean = context.getBean(annotation.ref());
    bean.m1();
}
```